# Avoid re-rendering whole list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a trivial list of items, which can update themselves. Update of one item triggers a re-render of all items. I provide unique keys for items, I'd expect React will skip the update of unchanged items. Even when `App` recreates `items` and `handleItemUpdate` function.

**What is wrong?**

> The Codepen example: https://codepen.io/enepom/pen/VwKdxZN
> Tap on one item prints 3 item renders in a console, not one.

Item component:

```
const Item = React.memo(({ id, count, onUpdate }) => {
  console.log('> ITEM RENDER', id);

  const handleClick = () => {
    onUpdate(id, count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={handleClick}>{id}: {count}</li>
  );
});
```

App component:

```
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setItems([
      { id: 'id1', count: 7 },
      { id: 'id2', count: 8 },
      { id: 'id3', count: 9 },
    ]);
  }, []);

  const handleItemUpdate = React.useCallback((itemId, count) => {
    const itemIndex = items.findIndex(item => item.id === itemId);
    if (itemIndex > -1) {
      const itemsCopy = items.slice();
      itemsCopy[itemIndex].count = count;

      setItems(itemsCopy);
    }
  }, [items, setItems]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item key={item.id} id={item.id} count={item.count} onUpdate={handleItemUpdate} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: Since the App has the state and setting the state will definitely re-render all the list. But React skips the update of un-changed item through virtual DOM diffing this means the Component will re-render but DOM won't get updated if no change found.
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html#what-is-the-virtual-dom

Comment: @TauseefAhmad ShadowDOM optimization helps of course but bides it the Item can contain many other things.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you update the items, the `handleItemUpdate` is recalculated becasue the `items` is changed , and in the useCallback dependencies array you have :

```
 [items, setItems]
```

So, each `Item` is rendered again as one property (onUpdate) has changed.

Comment: I understand it, but how to do it "right way" in React? Rerendering thousands of items is not an option. The task is usual I think.

Comment: isn't the `DOM shadow` technic here to avoid performance issue regarding regenerating whole lists ?

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem was in dependency on `items` in `handleItemUpdate`.

This code works as expected:

```
const handleItemUpdate = React.useCallback((itemId, count) => {
  setItems(prevItems => prevItems.map(item =>
    item.id === itemId
      ? { ...item, count }
      : item
  ));
}, [setItems]);
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/enepom/pen/qBaKYye

Comment: Ohh, in this you can even remove setItems. Since that is not changing.

Comment: I changed useCallback to useRef since there is no dependency. Even that works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it. React.memo does a shallow comparison, as you are passing an object it might different by reference even though values are the same, you need to implement arePropsEqual with your custom logic.

```
const Item = ({ id, count, onUpdate }) => {
  console.log('> ITEM RENDER', id);

  const handleClick = () => {
    onUpdate(id, count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={handleClick}>{id}: {count}</li>
  );
};
const arePropsEqual =(next,prev)=>{
  return next.id ===prev.id &&  next.count ===prev.count
}
const MemoItem = React.memo(Item,arePropsEqual);


const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setItems([
      { id: 'id1', count: 7 },
      { id: 'id2', count: 8 },
      { id: 'id3', count: 9 },
    ]);
  }, []);

  const handleItemUpdate = React.useCallback((itemId, count) => {
    const itemIndex = items.findIndex(item => item.id === itemId);
    if (itemIndex > -1) {
      const itemsCopy = items.slice();
      itemsCopy[itemIndex].count = count;

      setItems(itemsCopy);
    }
  }, [items, setItems]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <MemoItem key={item.id} id={item.id} count={item.count} onUpdate={handleItemUpdate} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to avoid unnecessary renders:

Add equality function to React.memo:

```
const Item = React.memo(({ id, count, onUpdate,items }) => {
  console.log('> ITEM RENDER', id);

  const handleClick = () => {
    onUpdate(id, count + 1,items);
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={handleClick}>{id}: {count}</li>
  );
}, (prev, next) => prev.id===next.id && prev.count===next.count);
```

```
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setItems([
      { id: 'id1', count: 7 },
      { id: 'id2', count: 8 },
      { id: 'id3', count: 9 },
    ]);
  }, []);

  const handleItemUpdate = React.useCallback((itemId, count,items) => {
    const itemIndex = items.findIndex(item => item.id === itemId);
    if (itemIndex > -1) {
      const itemsCopy = items.slice();
      itemsCopy[itemIndex].count = count;

      setItems(itemsCopy);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Item key={item.id} id={item.id} count={item.count} onUpdate={handleItemUpdate} items={items}/>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```